# FlaskForm wtforms multiple input fields single submit

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Using FlaskForm and SelectMultipleField, I'm creating a table of choices allowing for multiple selection to be ranked: 1, 2, 3, ... .

In order to place the choices in a grid pattern on a table, I made each row it's own instance of SelectMultipleField.

The submit button is only returning the values of the first instance of SelectMultipleField (dogs).

How can I get the submit button to return values in all instances of SelectMultipleField?

Here's the class in my forms module:

```
class LPRForm(FlaskForm):
    party = ['Dogs', 'Cats', 'Rabbits', 'Birds']
    dog = [('', 'D. Duke'), ('', 'R. Rusty'), \
             ('', 'T. Tucker'), ('', 'R. Roger')]
    cat = [('', 'S. Shadow'), ('', 'M. Misty'), \
             ('', 'P. Patch'), ('', 'P. Paws')]
    rabbit = [('', ''), ('', 'C. Clover'), ('', ''), ('', '')]
    bird = [('', 'P. Pikachu'), ('', 'S. Starburst'), \
              ('', ''), ('', 'F. Flighty')]

    vote_dog = SelectMultipleField('District', choices=dog, 
                        option_widget=widgets.TextInput() )
    vote_cat = SelectMultipleField('District', choices=cat, 
                        option_widget=widgets.TextInput() )
    vote_rabbit = SelectMultipleField('District', choices=rabbit, 
                        option_widget=widgets.TextInput() )
    vote_bird = SelectMultipleField('District', choices=bird, 
                        option_widget=widgets.TextInput() )

    submit = SubmitField('Cast Ballot')
```

Here's the relevant protion of the html file:

```
<table style="width:100%" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td>  </td>
    {% for vote in form.vote_dog %}
        {% if vote.label != '': %}
            <td>{{ vote(size="2") }}</td> <td>{{ vote.label }}</td>

        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>  </td>
    {% for vote in form.vote_cat %}
        {% if vote.label != '': %}
            <td>{{ vote(size="2") }}</td> <td>{{ vote.label }}</td>

        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>  </td>
    {% for vote in form.vote_rabbit %}
        {% if vote.label != '': %}
            <td>{{ vote(size="2") }}</td> <td>{{ vote.label }}</td>

        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>  </td>
    {% for vote in form.vote_bird %}
        {% if vote.label != '': %}
            <td>{{ vote(size="2") }}</td> <td>{{ vote.label }}</td>

        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

{{ form.submit }}
```

And the view module:

```
@app.route('/lpr', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def lpr():
    form = LPRForm() 
    return render_template('lpr.html', title='Home', form=form)
```

Comment: Does your html template have the form tags? Also `lpr()` will need `form = LPRForm(request.POST)` or similar, otherwise you are always processing a new form with no user data submitted (the form for `GET` method).

Comment: @progmatico My template does not have form tags.  I'm using `form=LPRForm()` and the browser is submitting the user data back to the server.  What's the purpose of `request.POST`?

Comment: Humm... Your code is ok. I suggested the usual pattern with bottle and WTForms. Looks like Flask has slight differences, the pattern does not apply. `request.POST` gets you a `MultiDict` in bottle and then you instantiate the form with it as a template for the form object attributes (after the post action the fields will be filled). I think from the Flask docs there is no `request.POST`,   and looks like it is not needed this way. Probably `request.form` gives the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by using FormField.  However, the documentation gives a default separator as `-`.  Additionally, I explicitly identified `separator='-'`, but only when I used `.` as a separator, when calling the class, did it work properly, ... even with `separator='-'`.